# Change width of Bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, width

I need to add `Bootstrap` container + 60px.

How I can do it, without changing `Bootstrap` itself ?

I've tried this media query, but it doesn't work.

```css
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .container{
            max-width: 1260px;
        }
    }
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your css code to 1260px, in case you dont wan't to change this in your bootstrap css file, make a new file and set it like so:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {  
    .container {
        width: 1260px;   
    } 
}
```

Make sure your new file is loaded below the original file of bootstrap css. Dont use max-width in this case. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried to add `!important` at the end of your **CSS** definition ?

Try this way:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1260px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it's still not working. Thank you for your answer anyway

Comment: Switch from max-width to width my second idea. Force a CSS property with `!important` could lead to some annoying bugs if you're using it too much.

Comment: You shouldn’t use important in this case because bootstrap allows you to change any variable via the bootstrap variable file or just load a new file to overrule the standard bootstrap units. Max-width isn’t needed and if you use it you won’t be able to use the fluid containers anymore as well!